ASP.NET Core app using Windows authentication, client does not negotiate after OPTIONS request
I'm having an issue with an ASP.NET Core app that is using Windows authentication and CORS. Windows auth works fine for direct API calls.  But the client fails to initiate negotiate after an OPTIONS request (the API returns 401 with www-authenticate Negotiate, and the client fails).
I've simplified the app down to a small sample.
Application setup:
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithOrigins("https://<my origin>")
                .WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate")
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
        });

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("<my cert>", "<my secret>");
            });
        });
        
        var app = builder.Build();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
        app.UseMiddleware<ResponseLoggingMiddleware>();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }

Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class IwaController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<IwaController> _logger;

    public IwaController(ILogger<IwaController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SiteCheck()
    {
        var identity = User?.Identity;

        if (identity == null || !identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("SiteCheck: Unauthorized request: " + identity?.IsAuthenticated.ToString() ?? "Null");
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("SiteCheck: Authorized request: {name} - {type}", identity?.Name, identity?.AuthenticationType);
        return new JsonResult(new { identity?.Name, identity?.AuthenticationType });
    }
}

Invoking sitecheck directly yields an expected Windows auth via negotiate. Doing a redirect from '' has a success OPTIONS request (204), with apparently appropriate headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<my origin>
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2024 00:10:42 GMT
Server: Kestrel

But the subsequent GET doesn't do the negotiate, it just fails with 401, even though the negotiate header is present in the response:
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2024 00:10:42 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Www-Authenticate: Negotiate

I've tried a number of different approaches with middleware ordering, custom authorization handlers, and CORS policy, as well as a bunch time googling, in Chat GPT, and searching Stackoverflow to no avail.
Would appreciate any suggestions or ideas anyone could provide.

Hi @Mike Nicolino, have you set both windowsAuthentication:true and anonymousauthentican:true?

Be careful about the order in which you apply your various middleware; in particular, a CORS middleware needs to be applied before any auth middleware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order

"The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Thanks for the feedback, I had  tried the above suggestions, and I have tried them again to confirm, but they did not resolve the issue; behavior remains the same.  Its very strange.
Going to investigate the browser side; maybe there's some interference in the client.

since this isn't happening when same-domain, I'd suspect it's the browser/OS that won't negotiate because the URL is not in the intranet or trusted zone.  (though in that case, I think you'd always see a prompt for username/password in browser)
